# tikz text decorations: direction of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-5.0, 5.0);
  \draw[red, ->,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={sample text}, text align=center,
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      every character/.style={ yshift=0.5ex}}}] (A) arc (0:90:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the direction of the text "sample text" without changing anything in the arc.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `reverse path`:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-5.0, 5.0);
  \draw[red, ->,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={sample text}, text align=center, reverse path,
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={
      yshift=0.5ex}}}] (A) arc (0:90:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]